# Помогите с решением задачи (преобразование строки) Python

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter
def duplicate_encode(word):
    cnt = dict(Counter(word.lower()))
    str = ''
    for i in word:
        if i in cnt:
            if cnt[i] < 2:
                str += '('
            else:
                str += ')'
    return str
```

The goal of this exercise is to convert a string to a new string where each character in the new string is "(" if that character appears only once in the original string, or ")" if that character appears more than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when determining if a character is a duplicate.

Examples
"din"      =>  "((("

"recede"   =>  "()()()"

"Success"  =>  ")())())"

"(( @"     =>  "))(("

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    dict = {}
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in dict:
            dict[letter] = '('
        else:
            dict[letter] = ')'
    str = ''
    for i in word:
        str += dict[i]
    return str
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
def duplicate_encode(word):
    cnt = dict(Counter(word.lower()))
    str = ''
    for i in word.lower():
        if i in cnt:
            if cnt[i] == 1:
                str += '('
            else:
                str += ')'
    return str
```

Почему то вот здесь **for i in word.lower():** не понятно для меня почему нужно было дописать **.lower()**

Comment: Потому что Вы, верно, поместили в словарь `cnt` строку со **строчными** символами, но затем, когда Вы проходили по строке через цикл, брали её такой, какой она была, в т.ч. **с прописными буквами**. Проще говоря, в `cnt` заносили данные для строчных символов, но сама строка так и осталась с возможными заглавными

Comment: Благодарю за пояснение :)